Configuring Ngix Virtual Hosts
Im having some issues configuring a virtual host in nginx. I followed this tutorial.
How to Install Magento 2 on Ubuntu with Windows 10/11 WSL
My vhost code in sites-available looks like this:
    server { 
    listen 80; 
    localhost http://localhost.t3chn0.com; 
    root /var/www/html/te3chn0.com/; 
    index index.php; 
    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    } 
    location ~ \.php$ { 
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; 
    } 
    location ~ /\.ht { 
        deny all; 
    } 
} 

The sites-available file is symlinked to sites-enabled
that returns this error:
t3chn0@MikesYoga:/var/www/html$ sudo nginx -t nginx: 
[emerg] unknown directive "t3chn0" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/t3chn0.com:3 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

When I clone the default file I get this error instead.
t3chn0@MikesYoga:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -t nginx: 
[emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Does anyone have any tips on what I might be doing wrong here? I'm new to Nginx. I could have figured this out in Apache.
Thanks in adavance
I tried switching from the code provided in the tutorial to the virtual host code commented out in the default file in nginx's sites-availble. This returns a differenet error
